# Submit form when ajax call is successful and prevent submit when ajax call fails

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-core

I want to be able to submit the form when the ajax call is successful and when it fails prevent the submission. Is there a way I can do this but not call the controller twice?

Controller returns

```
return File(excelPackage.GetAsByteArray(), "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet", fileName);
```

AJAX Call

```
//Form contains action : /api/Excel/DownloadExcel
$('#form').on('submit', function (e) {
    var submit = false;
    $.ajax({
        url: '/api/Excel/DownloadExcel',
        type: 'POST',
        data: $('#form').serialize(),
        async: false
    })
        .done(function () {
            submit = true;
        })
        .fail(function (response) {
            displayErrorMessage(response.status, response.responseText);
        });
    return submit;
});
```

Comment: You want to submit the form to another controller action?

Comment: I want to submit the form to download the file i returned, if i were to prevent the submission the file would be returned as data but not download.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have a form and you submit it, it will send a request to your server based on `action` attribute by default.

The problem is your form had sent a request, then you had also sent another request to server. So, your action in the controller had received 2 requests.

In your case, I suggest to call method `preventDefault` before sending request to server:

```
$('#form').on('submit', async function (e) {
    // add this line to your event to prevent submiting by default
    e.preventDefault();

    try {
        var file = await $.ajax({
            url: '/api/Excel/DownloadExcel',
            type: 'POST',
            data: $('#form').serialize(),
            async: false
        });

        console.log(file);

        return true;
    } catch (response) {
        displayErrorMessage(response.status, response.responseText);

        return false;
    }
});
```

I also rewrite your event to make it clear.

---

If you want to allow downloading the file without submitting, you can rewrite the event:

```
$('#form').on('submit', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    return false;
});

$('#download').on('click', async function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    // your ajax code goes here...
});
```

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear but the reason I wanted to I needed to call the request twice was because I wanted to check if the request was going to fail. After checking I would then submit the form again to download the returned file. For some reason when I prevent form submission the file is only returned but not automatically downloaded. Thanks for answering the question, I am quite new to programming.

Comment: @qwer1234asdf You don't need to send 2 requests to do the same thing. We can catch the event when it goes to fail. You can check my code again, the code inside `try` block will be called if your request becomes success, and `catch` block will be called when it goes to fail. There is still some way to do it twice but it seems you are wasting the resource. Imagine if you have 100 users who click download button at the same time, how many request would your action receive? 200 requests for 100 download times?